# Uploading via FTP using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, ftp

I have written a script to upload files from my computer to a external server. However I get the following error message:

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Filename invalid
```

I have tried changing the filename and etc but have had no luck. 
Here is my code:

```
$ftp_server = "ipaddress";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$destination_file = 'C:\ftp_root\borna\ttt.txt';
$source_file = 'C:\inetpub\ftp_test.txt'; 

// setup basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// check connection
if(!$conn_id){
    print "FTP connection has failed.<br>";
}else{
    print "FTP connection successfull.<br>";
}

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);

// check login
if(!login_result){
    print "FTP login credentials not recognised.<br>";
}else{
    print "FTP login credentials recognised.<br>";
}

// upload our file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);


// read upload status
if(!$upload){
    print "FTP upload has failed.<br>";
}else{
    print "FTP upload was successfull on file $source_file to $destination_file via $ftp_server.<br>";
}

// close the ftp stream
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: You're using `FTP_BINARY` yet attempting to upload an ASCII file. Use FTP_ASCII as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: hmm so just to be clear. when should i use what? Would be good if you could form an answer stating which transfer mode should be used for what files.

Comment: I have changed it to FTP_ASCII and i still get the same error.

Comment: Don't you need to escape both backslashes in the filename?
$source_file = "C:\inetpub\\ftp_test.txt";  should be $source_file = "C:\\inetpub\\ftp_test.txt"; or you could just use single quotes and then not worry about escaping the backslashes.

Comment: @ChipDean tried it. still made no difference.

Comment: Switch both of those double quotes to single quotes and remove the extra backslash. You aren't escaping the backslash in the desintation filename.

Comment: @ChipDean i did. Still get the same error.

Comment: @TestyTosty is the connection succesful

Comment: The backslashes might as well be forward slashes - they don't need escaping, and PHP on Windows will just convert them.

Comment: @TestyTosty usually an ftp user connects to a directory you should not have to put the whole path like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the error is correct:

```
$destination_file = "C:\ftp_root\borna\ttt.txt";
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

You're feeding it with a local path as target path (see the `C:` bit).

If unsure about what server paths will look like, just open the site with a regular FTP client.

If you don't have an FTP client you can download a free one called [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1). Install it, launch it, and type your FTP credentials (the piece of data you have in `$ftp_server`, `$username` and `$password` variables) in the top bar. Once you've established a connection you'll see remote paths in the **Remote Site** box.

Comment: Really unhelpfull answer for someone who is clueless at the moment. Can you tell me what a server path should look like?

Comment: What if he is uploading to a windows server?

Comment: @ChipDean Which I am, by the way.

Comment: @Testy: please don't call people unhelpful here - it's not very polite. I believe Alvaro is trying to help.

Comment: @TestyTosty I've edited my answer and tried to make it less unhelpful.

Comment: Even if you are connecting to a Windows server, the paths as seen over FTP usually do not look Windows-style. That's why @ÁlvaroG.Vicario suggested you to connect with FTP client and check what syntax the FTP server uses for paths.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - More than the syntax, the exact paths.

Comment: No more errors are generated but the file does not appear to be uploaded in the directory ;/